# why not use mouseup event target rather than position for "old school" drag-n-drop?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

So, from what I've seen nearly all the IE compatible drag-n-drop use positioning to determine where something is dropped. Doing something like mousedown, determine the position of all droppable, mouseup determine if we are in a droppable position. Why? I made a quick prototype, and it seems to work, which uses the event.target on mouseup (in jquery, so whatever that translates to elsewhere) to determine the drop element.

Is there a compelling reason not to do this? (use the e.target on mouseup). So, mousedown determines what is being dragged, and mouseup determines where it is dropped. Add some variable to make sure we're dragging, and remember what is dragged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: Because `e.target` on mouseup can refer to the element you're dragging (or its drag-ghost). If you drag an element, and it (or a translucent ghost-element) follows your cursor like when dragging a file on your desktop, your mouse will *always* be over the element you're dragging, when you mouse-up.

---

Alternatively, if there's no cursor-following, and no ghosting, `e.target` might refer to an element inside the "dropzone element" and not the dropzone itself.

For instance:

```
<div id="dropzone_element">
    <div id="previously_dropped_element" />
<div>

<div id="draggable_element" />
```

So if you drag the draggable element over the dropzone element and release the mouse, you're actually releasing the mouse over the previously dropped element inside the dropzone; not the dropzone itself.

In both cases, checking the mouse position is the only way to get the proper dropzone element.

Those would be my guesses, but I don't have IE to check the actual behavior.

---

Edit: In the 1st case position-checking is the only way. In the 2nd case, you could also check the target's ancestors to find the dropzone element, as pointed out by aephus in the comments. If, that is, the previously dropped element has actually be inserted into the dropzone's hierarchy, and not just been positioned to look like it is - although that would be a really weird thing to do :)

Comment: The second case does not make sense, you could always check the parent(s) of e.target to detect if it is the drop zone. Even if you allowed a drop zone inside a drop zone (not usually the case) you could still detect the nearest drop zone element.

Comment: I will reward you the bounty tomorrow for your first answer if none better have come in. It is a viable reason, but I'd like more feedback.

Comment: @aephus: True, in that case you could the ancestors of `target`. But you'd have to do that recursively for x number of nested elements, so in my opinion it'd still be cleaner to just check the mouse position and be done with it. But for dragging you really do need the visual feedback of something being dragged, so my money is on my first explanation. The 2nd case was just me brainstorming a bit :)

Comment: @aephus: Sounds good - I'm also curious to see what others come up with. As mentioned, my hypotheses are just theory and untested in IE, so who knows... :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to rely on position in a relatively static page, but when you have content showing up on mouse over and various other movements, it's a huge pain to recalculate the positions.

Comment: @aephus: Well, you only need to calculate the positions once, when the mouseup occurs. And anyway, if you have elements popping up on mouse overs, `target` wouldn't necessarily help you either, if you end up dropping something on an element that's just popped up in front of the dropzone.

Comment: @aephus: I think you forgot to give me the bounty :)

Comment: I thought I had awarded it days ago, but it does not appear so.

Answer (score 1):

The first quess: there is always lagging when you drag elements, especialy in IE. And mouse pointer can outrun or fall behind the dragging element. So on drop, pointer is not actualy over the dragging element, and - for small drop zones - not over the drop zone. Ajax libraries have to take this fact into account. And the only way to make it work predictably is to compare coordinates of dragging target and the drop zone.

The second quess: ajax libraries may give you an opportunity to use the `drop handler`. The `drop handler` is an element which is not child of the dropzone but it is covering the dropzone. And in this case there is no way to catch events by dropzone. But comparing the coordinates is still working. Why would someone cover the dropzone? Let's assume one has table. And one of cells is the dropzone. And now one wants to catch mousewheel event. One creates div (#scroller) with the same size as table and places it over the table. Then he puts another div (#eventgrabber) inside scroller. Eventgrabber is heigher then scroller. Now one is able to catch scroll event on scroller. But in order to be able to drag cells one have to assign eventgrabber as drag&drop handler.